# MySQL table creation error #1005

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE location_share (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,   
    user_id INT ,   
    circle_id INT ,   
    location_sharing_id  INT ,    
    CONSTRAINT fkuser1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
    CONSTRAINT fkcircle1 FOREIGN KEY (circle_id)
        REFERENCES circle(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
    CONSTRAINT fksharing_policy FOREIGN KEY (location_sharing_id) 
        REFERENCES share(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

Error message:

> error : #1005 - Can't create table `'.\phonetracker\location_share.frm'` (errno: 150)

Other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    contact_no VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    last_name VARCHAR(25) , 
    device_id VARCHAR(250)NOT NULL , 
    image_path VARCHAR(180) , 
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
    latitude VARCHAR(18) , 
    longitude VARCHAR(18) 
) ENGINE=INNODB

CREATE TABLE circle (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    name varchar(35)
) ENGINE=INNODB

CREATE TABLE share (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    policy VARCHAR(6) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
)
```

Comment: From [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html), "table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed".  Suggest formatting this query into multiple lines with indentations to make it more comprehensible for all.  Tip: here in Stack Overflow questions, if you begin each line with **four spaces** it will format it like code, as opposed to conversational text.

Comment: will you please tell me ,, what i have done wrong in foreign key constraint??                                                                                                                                  Thank you

Comment: I'm not liking that part `(user_id)REFERENCES`.  Try a space: `(user_id) REFERENCES`

Comment: I have tried with spaces but it is not working ...

Comment: table is not creating if i am not adding "ENGINE=INNODB" .... but i have to add this..

Comment: Is share INNODB?  Wild guess, does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3d04/1

Nothing wrong with your query, just need to be ordered, if you use `FOREIGN KEY` the parent table must be declared first.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    contact_no VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    last_name VARCHAR(25) , 
    device_id VARCHAR(250)NOT NULL , 
    image_path VARCHAR(180) , 
    password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
    latitude VARCHAR(18) , 
    longitude VARCHAR(18) 
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE circle (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    name varchar(35)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE share (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , 
    policy VARCHAR(6) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE location_share (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,   
    user_id INT ,   
    circle_id INT ,   
    location_sharing_id  INT ,    
    CONSTRAINT fkuser1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
    CONSTRAINT fkcircle1 FOREIGN KEY (circle_id)
        REFERENCES circle(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,    
    CONSTRAINT fksharing_policy FOREIGN KEY (location_sharing_id) 
        REFERENCES share(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

Comment: i have already ordered all the tables ... but still it is not working